# swift animate all added views alpha

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uianimation, animatewithduration

I want to animate all views (based on tag) with an alpha change, but I am getting a "cannot assign alpha to view" error. What would be a good way to do this?

All the views have an alpha of 0 upon being added as a subview of myCustomView

```
func transitionEffects() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        for view in self.myCustomView.subviews {
            if(view.tag != 999) {
                view.alpha = 1
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Apart from the error, I'd be surprised if your code works as you intend, specifically I'd be surprised if it animates the alpha of multiple views.  Let us know if it does as I am curious.

Comment: So *multiple* views have their alpha animated? Not just one? That's interesting.

Comment: yep, multiple views!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Swift needs to know the kind of objects inside the subviews `NSArray` before sending methods. 
`NSArray` is automatically converted in a swift `Array` of `AnyType` objects, thus it doesn't know which kind of objects are extracted from the array. By casting the array to be an array of `UIView`s objects everything should work fine.

```
func transitionEffects() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        for view in self.myCustomView.subviews as [UIView] {
            if (view.tag != 999) {
                view.alpha = 1
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I would expect the Swift compiler to complain unless you wrote `view.alpha = 1.0`. Swift doesn't automatically "promote" scalars from int to float to double like C/Objective-C does. Curious that it doesn't.

Comment: That makes sense Duncan, but as far as I remember when I copied this code in an app of mine it didn't. Mumble.. But yours is good point.

Comment: @DuncanC that's because `CGFloat` is `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.